# How to Upload a Photo From iOS Application to Particular FaceBook Page?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am Newbie in iOS Development. I make an application that take a Photo From Camera and Save it in to Mobile Gallery But i want when User pick up the Photo From Camera then i want to Post this Photo From Particular Facebook Page like as my facebook page [link](https://www.facebook.com/SundaleLtd?refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.au%2F) how it Possible? If it is possible then please Give me Solution For it and Give any Resource For it if it Possible.

And Here my FaceBook Page is Public.

Here My Code for ImagePicker

```
-(IBAction)cameraButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *imgpicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    imgpicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imgpicker.mediaTypes=@[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
    imgpicker.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:imgpicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You have not Camera" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
[self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Celebrate Christmas" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error)
{
    if (error!=nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: we can post external image [i.e. url] in app to Facebook page , it is possible , but I think this is not possible, if user capture the image from camera or gallery

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik then how i post my Saved Gallery Image In to FaceBook Page? Here i am Not an admin of the Page.

Comment: no need to admin authentication , just add the page id and page access token when u post the data to Facebook, it automatically taken the admin authentication

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Okh Thnx Bro. Please Give me Any Link for Update A photo In to Facebook page.

Comment: i give the sample with external image , i worked in my last project

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Then Please Give me it.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Why are you Erase Answer From Here?